# Do missions count towards trade rank?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Do missions you take at a station count towards your trade rank?  I've read that smuggling counts towards gaining rank, so I want to know if general trading and / or Long Range Smuggling (from Robigo etc) counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Trade missions count towards trade rank, including Long-Range Smuggling. I went up a couple trade ranks doing smuggling missions out of Robigo.